# React Functional Component - Where to store transformed value calculated from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-functional-component

Let's say I have the following heavy calculation function:

```
function heavyCalculator(str:string):string{
  //Do some heavy calculation
  return result;
}
```

```
function SomeComponent({prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4}:Props){
  useEffect(()=>{
    const result = heavyCalculator(prop3);
    //How should i store the result?
  },[prop3])
  return <span>{resultFromHeavyCalculation}</span>;
}
```

How should I store the calculation result in a way that it won't get recalculated on every render / prop change?

Should I use "useMemo" or use "useState" and set it inside the "useEffect" only when prop3 is changed?

Comment: Yes you can use useState to save the result. And if prop3 changed then result will be recalculated again and result state will be updated.

Comment: I think you need [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook

Comment: just with `useMemo` no need for `useEffect`. useMemo takes as well an array of values based on it should re-run. So unless you change one of those the value will not be re-calculated.

Comment: @demark-pro why useContext hook needed here? There is no prop drills here or nor this result will be used by other component. Every prop3 change result will be recalculated here. so useState is enough to save result.

Comment: `const resultFromHeavyCalculation = useMemo(() => heavyCalculator(prop3), [prop3]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the prime use-case for `useMemo`. Although your approach with `useEffect(() => ..., [prop3])` would also work if you store the result in a `useState` variable, useMemo would require less boilerplate:

```
function SomeComponent({prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4}:Props){
  const resultFromheavyCalculation = useMemo(() => heavyCalculator(prop3), [prop3])
  return <span>{resultFromHeavyCalculation}</span>;
}
```

You can learn more about [useMemo in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). The example there is actually very similar to the one you're providing.

If you really set your mind on avoiding `useMemo` at all costs, the answer would be:

```
    function SomeComponent({prop1,prop2,prop3,prop4}:Props){
      const [resultFromHeavyCalculation, setResultFromHeavyCalculation] = useState();
      useEffect(()=>{
          const result = heavyCalculator(prop3);
          setResultFromHeavyCalculation(result);
      },[prop3]), [prop3])
      return <span>{resultFromHeavyCalculation}</span>;
    }
```